# show products of quasi projective varieties are quasi projective varieties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

show that the products of quasi projective varieties are quasi projective varieties.

use the hint: $(X_1 \setminus X_0) \times (Y_1 \setminus Y_0) = (X_1 \times Y_1) \setminus ((X_0 \times Y_1)\cup (X_1 \times Y_0)). $

attempt: let $X_0 \subset X \subset \mathbb{P}^m$, where $X_0$ is open and $X$ is closed and similarly for $Y_0$.
Then $X_0 \times Y_0 = (X \setminus X_1) \times (Y\setminus Y_1) = (X \times Y) \setminus ((X_1 \times Y) \cup (X \setminus Y_1))$.

Could someone please verify this? I am stuck after this. 
I want to show $X_0 \times Y_0$ is open under the Zariski topology so that it's quasi projective variety

Comment: So using your argument, can you see that it's enough to show product of projective is projective?

Comment: What are $X_1$ and $Y_1$?

Comment: Hint: Use the Segre embedding.

Comment: How would you do that ? I am given the hint . I don't know how the serge embedding could help